# Find eigenvalue of matrix given eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix:

$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -3  \\
2 &  1
\end{bmatrix}  
$

And its eigenvector is :

$v=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}  
$

I would like to find its eigenvalue. This is my attempt, however I am doing something wrong:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -3  \\
2 &  1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}  =
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}  
$

Then...

$6x -3y = 4$

$2x + y = 3$

Elimination...

$x = 13/12$

$y = 10/12$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
13/12 \\
10/12
\end{bmatrix}  = \lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}  
$

For the final part, I can't figure out a value for $\lambda$ that satisfies both `4` and `3`, which means I am doing something wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure you did not mean that the eigenvalues are $4$ and $3$? I think you are confusing the two eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: no, the question I'm doing states that [4,3] is the eigenvector of the matrix

Comment: If you find the characteristic polynomial of $P$ you get $x^2-7x+12$.  Amzoti is right.

Comment: @Balboa: your book has an error! It is easy to verify what I am stating.

Comment: hmmm I see, the question has been driving me nuts, at least now I know how to properly find an eigenvalue though.

Comment: For what it is worth, the eigenvectors are $[1,1]$and $[-3,2]$ for $3,4$ respectively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -3  \\
2 &  1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}  =
\lambda \begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and then find $\lambda$. (By the way, when I do this in my head, I find that no such lambda exists, i.e., that this is NOT an eigenvector of the given matrix...but maybe my in-the-head arithmetic isn't so reliable.)

Given Amzoti's comment, you need to write
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -3  \\
2 &  1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}  =
a\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a$ is either $4$ or $3$, and find the associated eigenvector. If $v$ is an eigenvector, so is $2v$, so you'll have to pick either $x$ or $y$ and then solve for the other.

Comment: my scratch work agrees, $[4,3]^T$ is not an eigenvector.